# Duplicated response promise with $q.all in angularJS + express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

When using $q.all() to get multiple responses, I get the same values in the response object. I get as many objects back as promises declared, but all the 'name' fields have the same value (the last one, 3).

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $q, myService) {

   $scope.myList = [];

   $scope.create = function() {
      var newObject;
      var promises = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        newObject = { name: i };
        promises[i] = myService.create(newObject);
      }
      $q.all(promises).then(
       function (response) {
         $scope.myList = response;
       }
      );
   };
}
```

And here's my service:

```
    .service('myService', function ($http, $q, baseURL) {

       this.create = function(object) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         //console.log shows that object still has the proper 'name' value
         $http.post(url, object).then(
            function (response) {
              // console.log shows that all response objects have the same 'name' value.
              deferred.resolve(response);
            }
          );
         return deferred.promise;
       };
}
```

Any input is appreciated since it's my first approach to promises in Angular.

Comment: what is `p` in `promises[p] = myService.create(newObject);`?

Comment: typo, fixed above, thanks! problem persists of course

Comment: So objects on this line `$http.post(url, object)` all have the correct names, but inside the then function, each `response` object has the same name value?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said.

Comment: What is the server supposed to be returning? A mirror image of the sent data? If that's the only things I can think of are 1) there's only 1 request being sent (which doesn't look like the case) and 2) the server is only processing 1 of these OR is only returning the last request received...

Comment: The server is supposed to return a new object, containing the 'name' attribute + the _id field generated by mongoose.

There are always 2 request sends (checked on the console) both to the same URL, and both return the same 'name' though with different _id's.

So it seems that the post function in my service is not reading the first object correctly. I assume it gets replaced by the new value, but preventing that is supposed to be the whole point of making the promise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121000/discussion-between-stevenelberger-and-daniel-ramirez-torres).

Comment: You might want to try removing the defer and resolve code that's unnecessary. It makes it easier to debug code if you don't have "fluff" in it http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by moving the newObject declaration inside the loop, as we redeclare the variable, the promise keeps a copy of the previous value to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what it is you are trying to do, but the way you have your code written, it will always end up with the name of the last one because you are over-writing your promise each time.  You would need to do something similar to the following:

```
      var newObject;
  var promises = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    newObject = { name: i };
    var promise = myService.create(newObject);
   promises.push(promise);
  }
  $q.all(promises).then(
   function (response) {
     $scope.myList = response;
   }
  );
```

};

Comment: isn't promises.push(value) the same as promises[index] = value?

Comment: No. You never actually filled the array, you just kept over-writing it each time.

Comment: Still receiving the same repeated response using push.

Comment: That's interesting, because when I run the code I get 4 objects names 0-3.

Comment: Re-checked, still returning the same values for every object. The express router receives them already with the same 'name' values.

Comment: You did remove the '[i]' right?  It should just be promises.push not promises[i].push.  There must be something else going on.